# How to sum values by specific string in a column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for a solution in. Namely for dataset = data, I would like to add values according to column X or column Y. Column selection is determined by "string" in column Z.

```
dataset:

data
    Z    X    Y
"aaa"    1    10
"aaa"    1    10
"bbb"    2    20
"bbb"    2    20
"ccc"    3    30
"ccc"    3    30

effect1:

data1
    Z  sumX  sumY
"aaa"   2    20
"bbb"   4    40
"ccc"   6    60

effect2: 
data2_sum
    Z    totalXY
"aaa"    2
"bbb"    4
"ccc"    60
```

Thank you in advance for your help.
Regards
Peter

Comment: It isn't clear how you get the totals in effect2. The sums are the sum of X for the first two and of Y for the third one.

Comment: totalXY is the sum of totalsumX for "aaa" and totalsumX for "bbb" and totalsumY for "ccc". It is important that in effect 1 sums according to the variable "Z", but in the final podusowanie for "aaa" and "bbb" takes sums from totalsumX, but for the string "ccc" from totalsumY.

Summarizing:
If there is a string "aaa" or "bbb" in the column Z, it sums according to totalsumX
If in the column Z is the string "ccc" it sums according to totalsumY

Answer (score 0):

For your `effect1` the code is straightforward using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
      Z =  c("aaa", "aaa","bbb","bbb","ccc","ccc"),
      X = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
      Y = c(10,10,20,20,30,30))

df %>% 
  group_by(Z) %>% 
  summarise(sumX = sum(X),
            sumY = sum(Y))
```

It is not clear what you want to calculate in `effect2`

Comment: In effect2 I would like to get the sums for "aaa", "bbb" and "ccc" taking into account other columns. For example, if columns X are fixed costs, and Y are variable costs, then in effect2 I would like to do, for example, the sum of costs assuming that for "ccc" only variable costs are counted.

Comment: Fro m the information you provide, that´s not clear and can not be solved.

Comment: totalXY is the sum of totalsumX for "aaa" and totalsumX for "bbb" and totalsumY for "ccc". It is important that in effect 1 sums according to the variable "Z", but in the final podusowanie for "aaa" and "bbb" takes sums from totalsumX, but for the string "ccc" from totalsumY.

Summarizing:
If there is a string "aaa" or "bbb" in the column Z, it sums according to totalsumX
If in the column Z is the string "ccc" it sums according to totalsumY

Answer (score 0):

1. There is the raw data below:

data
    Z    X    Y
"aaa"    1    10
"aaa"    1    10
"bbb"    2    20
"bbb"    2    20
"ccc"    3    30
"ccc"    3    30

In the first step I would like to summarize the X and Y columns for Z variables (ie "aaa", "bbb", "ccc")

effect1:

data1
    Z  sumX  sumY
"aaa"   2    20
"bbb"   4    40
"ccc"   6    60

Next, I would like the code for effect2 to add up according to such dependence.

1. Create a data frame from the Z columns and the new totalXY column
   1.1. If the "aaa" or "bbb" column in the Z column is in the new totalXY column, insert the value from effect1 from the sumX column
   1.2. If the column "Z" is "ccc" then in the new column totalXY (effect2) insert the value from effect1 from the column sumY

effect2: 
data2_sum
    Z    totalXY
"aaa"    2
"bbb"    4
"ccc"    60